# Why do people use tarballs?

Tags: linux, package, archive

As a primarily Windows developer, perhaps I'm missing something cultural in the Linux community, but it has always confused me.

When downloading something that the files are first put into a `.tar` archive then *zipped*. Why the two-step process? Doesn't *zipping* achieve the file grouping? Is there some other benefit that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Usually you just combine compression and file grouping to a single command.

tar -zcf file.tar.gz some file names

Comment: No one mentioned that transferring 1000000 files w/ size 1 byte is more expensive than transferring 1 file w/ size 1000000 bytes.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

`bzip` and `gzip` work on single files, not groups of files. Plain old `zip` (and `pkzip`) operate on groups of files and have the concept of the archive built-in.

The *nix philosophy is one of the small tools that do specific jobs very well and can be chained together. That's why there are two tools here that have specific tasks, and they're designed to fit well together. It also means you can use tar to group files and then you have a choice of a compression tool (`bzip`, `gzip`, etc).

Comment: Answered faster, and a little better than I did - guess I'll go back to work!

Comment: I beat you by 4 minutes, and that's an eternity in stack overflow time. :-)

Comment: It's worth noting that both tar and gzip are useful on their own which is why they're separated.  With some clever use of pipes, I once moved a folder from one computer to another by tarring, zipping and piping over SSH, then unzipping and untarring on the destination.  One command, no temp files.

Comment: So basically you are saying that *nix people inflict tarballs on the world because of a stubborn refusal to adjust their behaviour to use modern tools and techniques?

Comment: You could also say that they stick with what has been proven to work well, rather than changing things and breaking compatibility. .tar.gz can be done in a single step regardless just like so-called modern tools and techniques (Please Register WinZip).

Comment: @David please clarify inflict.  Its only an issue if you're using out of date tools yourself.  Most modern tools will treat zips and tarballs the same way.  gzip compression is pretty much the same as zip, bzip2 is generally smaller.

Comment: @Steve g, looks like I'm hoisted by my own petard there :)

Comment: GNU tar has inbuilt support for gzip and bzip2 in a way that you can teach tar to call them yourself: Using -z or -j command line options, the lazy user can build and unpack a tar.gz / tar.bz2 on-the-fly, without a need to pipe herself.

Comment: create bzip: tar -jcpvf foo.tar.bz2 <dir>
unpack bzip: tar -jxvf foo.tar.bz2
create gz: tar -zcpvf foo.tar.gz <dir>
unpack gz: tar -zxvf foo.tar.gz

Comment: tar is a format for combining groups of files in a single file. There is no reason why this should require it to be compressed. A modern replacement for tar would probably be ISO9660 rather than zip.

That you can optionally compress it with any algorithm you choose is one of the benefits of the Unix design.

Comment: And lets dont' forget that the tar+gzip approach is both computationally cheaper, and achieves better compression, than winzip. (Although, I'll admit to not actually benchmarking that...)

Comment: I cannot believe that nobody has either edited the question, or left a comment mentioning the (imo) entire point of using `tar` archives: **Linux filesystem permission support**. What would happen if you downloaded a Debian package, your package manager installed it, but none of the executables were executable? That's the _real_ reason why everybody uses tarballs... ;)

Answer (score 31):

An important distinction is in the nature of the two kinds of archives.

TAR files are little more than a concatenation of the file contents with some headers, while gzip and bzip2 are stream compressors that, in tarballs, are applied to the whole concatenation.

ZIP files are a concatenation of individually compressed files, with some headers. Actually, the DEFLATE algorithm is used by both zip and gzip, and with appropriate binary adjusting, you could take the payload of a gzip stream and put it in a zip file with appropriate header and dictionary entries.

This means that the two different archive types have different trade-offs. For large collections of small files, TAR followed by a stream compressor will normally result in higher compression ratio than ZIP because the stream compressor will have more data to build its dictionary frequencies from, and thus be able to squeeze out more redundant information. On the other hand, a (file-length-preserving) error in a ZIP file will only corrupt those files whose compressed data was affected. Normally, stream compressors cannot meaningfully recover from errors mid-stream. Thus, ZIP files are more resilient to corruption, as part of the archive will still be accessible.

Comment: Thank you for the distinction between zip and tar+gzip!

Comment: +1 for the distinction between "compressing an aggregate file" and "aggregating compressed files".

Comment: The reason for tar allowing better compression ratios and zip being more resilient on the other hand is explained by the fact that tar is a kind of [solid compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_compression) while zip is non-solid.

Comment: @Barry, So in conclusion who wins? (assuming we're using modern OSes)

Comment: @Pacerier I don't think there's any winning. Zips are better for random access and for use by people on Windows. Tarballs have higher out of the box compatibility on Linux and Unix. Tarballs have slightly higher compression but you need to decompress the whole thing to access anything. Both support arbitrary compression algorithms, but it's much easier to mix and match with tarballs. Depending on the goal, either could be better.

Answer (score 27):

It's odd that no-one else has mentioned that modern versions of GNU `tar` allow you to compress as you are bundling:

```
tar -czf output.tar.gz directory1 ...

tar -cjf output.tar.bz2 directory2 ...
```

You can also use the compressor of your choosing provided it supports the '`-c`' (to stdout, or from stdin) and '`-d`' (decompress) options:

```
tar -cf output.tar.xxx --use-compress-program=xxx directory1 ...
```

This would allow you to specify any alternative compressor.

[*Added*: If you are extracting from `gzip` or `bzip2` compressed files, GNU `tar` auto-detects these and runs the appropriate program.  That is, you can use:

```
tar -xf output.tar.gz
tar -xf output.tgz        # A synonym for the .tar.gz extension
tar -xf output.tar.bz2
```

and these will be handled properly.  If you use a non-standard compressor, then you need to specify that when you do the extraction.]

The reason for the separation is, as in the selected answer, the separation of duties.  Amongst other things, it means that people could use the '`cpio`' program for packaging the files (instead of `tar`) and then use the compressor of choice (once upon a time, the preferred compressor was `pack`, later it was `compress` (which was much more effective than `pack`), and then `gzip` which ran rings around both its predecessors, and is entirely competitive with `zip` (which has been ported to Unix, but is not native there), and now `bzip2` which, in my experience, usually has a 10-20% advantage over `gzip`.

[*Added*: someone noted in their answer that `cpio` has funny conventions.  That's true, but until GNU `tar` got the relevant options ('`-T -`'), `cpio` was the better command when you did not want to archive everything that was underneath a given directory -- you could actually choose exactly which files were archived.  The downside of `cpio` was that you not only *could* choose the files -- you *had* to choose them.  There's still one place where `cpio` scores; it can do an in-situ copy from one directory hierarchy to another without any intermediate storage:

```
cd /old/location; find . -depth -print | cpio -pvdumB /new/place
```

Incidentally, the '`-depth`' option on `find` is important in this context - it copies the contents of directories before setting the permissions on the directories themselves.  When I checked the command before entering the addition to this answer, I copied some read-only directories (555 permission); when I went to delete the copy, I had to relax the permissions on the directories before '`rm -fr /new/place`' could finish.  Without the `-depth` option, the `cpio` command would have failed.  I only re-remembered this when I went to do the cleanup - the formula quoted is that automatic to me (mainly by virtue of many repetitions over many years).
]

Comment: An expanded ZIP format could accommodate plug-in stream compressors just as much as TAR, but without a suitable IPC protocol it would likely be slower due to excessive exec'ing of subprocesses.

Comment: my goto command: 

tar -xfvz tarpkg.tar.gz  (replace the z with a j for bz2 compressed archives)

Comment: @Redbeard: tar auto-detects gzip and bzip2 on extract -- for create, you have to tell it what to do, but I just use -xf (or -xvf) and the tar file name.

Answer (score 15):

The funny thing is, you can get behaviour not anticipated by the creators of `tar` and `gzip`.  For example, you can not only gzip a tar file, you can also tar gzipped files, to produce a `files.gz.tar` (this would technically be closer to the way `pkzip` works).  Or you can put another program into the pipeline, for example some cryptography, and you can choose an arbitrary order of tarring, gzipping and encrypting.  Whoever wrote the cryptography program does not have to have the slightest idea how his program would be used, all he needs to do is read from standard input and write to standard output.

Comment: When generating the file, remember to encrypt after compressing, not before, because the output of encryption looks random and is hard to compress.

Answer (score 9):

In the Unix world, most applications are designed to do one thing, and do it well. The most popular zip utilities in Unix, gzip and bzip2, only do file compression. tar does the file concatenation. Piping the output of tar into a compression utility does what's needed, without adding excessive complexity to either piece of software.

Answer (score 7):

Another reason it is so prevalent is that tar and gzip are on almost the entire *NIX install base out there.  I believe this is probably the single largest reason.  It is also why zip files are extremely prevalent on Windows, because support is built in, regardless of the superior routines in RAR or 7z.

GNU tar also allows you to create/extract these files from one command (one step):

- **Create an Archive:**
- `tar -cfvj destination.tar.bz2 *.files`
- `tar -cfvz destination.tar.gz *.files`
- **Extract an Archive:**  *(the -C part is optional, it defaults to current directory)*
- `tar -xfvj archive.tar.bz2 -C destination_path`
- `tar -xfvz archive.tar.gz -C destination_path`

These are what I have committed to memory from my many years on Linux and recently on Nexenta (OpenSolaris).

Comment: Actually, it's the other way round: zip is built in Windows *now* because it was prevalent in DOS and early versions of Windows.

Comment: I like to use RAR on Windows, tar.bz2 on Linux

Comment: You might note the weird (not compatible with getopt()) option parsing, and the dash is optional because tar pre-dates the standard conventions of Unix command options.

Answer (score 5):

I think you were looking for more of historical context to this. The original zip was for a single file. Tar is used to place multiple files into a single file. Therefore tarring and zipping is the two step process. Why it is still so dominant today is anyone's guess.

From wikipedia for [Tar_ (file_format)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(file_format))

> In computing, tar (derived from tape archive) is both a file format (in the form of a type of archive bitstream) and the name of the program used to handle such files. The format was standardized by POSIX.1-1988 and later POSIX.1-2001. Initially developed as a raw format, used for tape backup and other sequential access devices for backup purposes, it is now commonly used to collate collections of files into one larger file, for distribution or archiving, while preserving file system information such as user and group permissions, dates, and directory structures.

Answer (score 4):

### tar is UNIX as UNIX is tar

In my opinion the reason of **still** using `tar` today is that it's one of the (probably rare) cases where the UNIX approach just made it perfectly right from the very beginning.

Taking a closer look at the stages involved in creating archives I hope you'll agree that the way the separation of different tasks takes place here is **UNIX philosophy** at its very best:

- one tool (`tar` to give it a name here) specialized in transforming **any** selection of files, directories and symbolic links including **all** relevant meta-data like timestamps, owners and permissions into one byte stream.
- and just another arbitrarily interchangeable tool (`gzip` `bz2` `xz` to name just a few options) that transforms **any** input stream of bytes into another (hopefully) smaller output stream.

Using such and approach delivers a whole couple of benefits to the user as well as to the developer:

- **extensibility**
  Allowing to couple `tar` with **any** compression algorithm already existing or **any** compression algorithm yet still to be developed **without** having to change anything on the inner workings of `tar` at all.

  As soon as the all brand new "hyper-zip-utra" or whater compression tool comes out you're already ready to use it embracing your new servant with the whole power of `tar`.
- **stability**
  `tar` has been in heavy use since the early 80es tested and been run on numberous operating systems and machines.

  Preventing the need to **reinvent** the wheel in implementing storing ownership, permissions, timestamps and the like **over and over again** for **every** new archiving tool not only saves a lot of (otherwise unnecessarily spent) time in development, but also guarantees the same **reliability** for every new application.
- **consistency** The user interface just stays the same all the time.

  There's no need to remember that to restore permissions using tool A you have to pass option `--i-hope-you-rember-this-one` and using tool B you have to use `--this-time-its-another-one`  while using tool C it's `--hope-you-didnt-try-with-tool-as-switch.

  Whereas in utilizing tool D you would have really messed up it if you didn't use `--if-you-had-used-tool-bs-switch-your-files-would-have-been-deleted-now`.

Answer (score 3):

**tar** is popular mostly for historic reasons. There are several alternatives readily available. Some of them are around for nearly as long as tar, but couldn't surpass tar in popularity for several reasons.

- cpio (alien syntax; theoretically more consistent, but people like what they know, tar prevailed)
- ar (popular a long time ago, now used for packing library files)
- shar (self extracting shell scripts, had all sorts of issues; used to be popular never the less)
- zip (because of licensing issues it wasn't readily available on many Unices)

A major advantage (and downside) of tar is that it has neither file header, nor central directory of contents. For many years it therefore never suffered from limitations in file-size (until this decade where an 8 Gb limit on files inside the archive became a problem, solved years ago).

Apperantly the one downside of tar.gz (or ar.Z for that matter), which is that you have to uncompress the whole archive for extracting single files and listing archive contents, never hurt people enough to make them defect from tar in significant numbers.

Comment: Old versions of tar did not have header information; new (POSIX-compatible, USTAR) versions of tar (eg GNU tar) do.  The 'file' command understands this.

Answer (score 2):

gzip and bzip2 is simply a compressor, not an archiver-software. Hence, the combination. You need the tar-software to bundle all the files.

ZIP itself, and RAR aswell are a combination of the two processes.

Answer (score 2):

Usually in the *nux world, bundles of files are distributed as tarballs and then optionally gzipped.  Gzip is a simple file compression program that doesn't do the file bundling that tar or zip does.

At one time, zip didn't properly handle some of the things that Unix tar and unix file systems considered normal, like symlinks, mixed case files, etc.  I don't know if that's changed, but that's why we use tar.

Comment: *nux - Linux, Unux, Solarnux?

Comment: @mackenir - don't forget POSUX. :-)

Comment: @mackenir - Or should that be POSNUX?

Answer (score 1):

Tar = Groups files in 1 files

GZip = Zip the file

They split the process in 2. That's it.

In the Windows environnement that you might be more used to use the WinZip or WinRar that do a Zip. The Zip process of these software do group the file and zipping but you simply do not see that process.

Comment: It's not the best explanation, given that the "zip" files the OP is used to in Windows, already incorporate the grouping.

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason why mac users love disk images: They are a really convenient way to archive stuff and then pass it around, up-/download or email it etc.

And easier to use and more portable than zips IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

In my Altos-XENIX days (1982) we started using tar (tape archiver) to extract files from 5 1/4 floppies or streaming tape as well as copy to these media. It's functionality is very similar to the BACKUP.EXE and RESTORE.EXE commands in DOS 5.0 and 6.22 as supplements, allowing you to span multiple media if it couldn't fit in only one. The drawback was that if one of the multiple media had problems, the whole thing was worthless. tar and dd originate from UNIX SYstem III and has remained a standard release utility with UNIX-like OS' probably for backward compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Tar is not only a file format, but it is a tape format.  Tapes store data bit-by-bit. Each storage implementation was custom.  Tar was the method by which you could take data off a disk, and store it onto tape in a way that other people could retrieve it without your custom program.

Later, the compression programs came, and *nix still only had one method of creating a single file that contained multiple files.

I believe it's just inertia that has continued with the tar.gz trend. Pkzip started with both compression and archival in one fell swoop, but then DOS systems didn't typically have tape drives attached!

From wikipedia for Tar_ (file_format)

> In computing, tar (derived from tape archive) is both a file format (in the form of a type of archive bitstream) and the name of the program used to handle such files. The format was standardized by POSIX.1-1988 and later POSIX.1-2001. Initially developed as a raw format, used for tape backup and other sequential access devices for backup purposes, it is now commonly used to collate collections of files into one larger file, for distribution or archiving, while preserving file system information such as user and group permissions, dates, and directory structures.

Comment: Strictly speaking tar is a file format - it's just that on unix tapes are just another file.

Comment: Actually, tar was not a file format to begin with. Tapes did not have file systems, so tar was created as a patch for not having a file system.

Answer (score 0):

As a Windows Developer it is understandable how **tarballs** seem strange. The word `tar` stands for Tape Archive. Think reel-to-reel tape recorders.

In the Windows world programs are generally installed with a `setup.exe` or `install.exe` which work all kinds of wizardry in the registry, creating directories and installing `.dll` (Dynamic Link Library) files.

In Linux, Ubuntu in particular from my own experience, package managers take care of taking an application and installing it *most of the time*. In Ubuntu the developer creates a package ending in `.deb` (Debian, which Ubuntu is based upon). The basic syntax to install a `.deb` is:

```
sudo apt install <package_name>
```

Although this is relatively straight forward for a user, it is a lot of work for developers to create a `.deb` package and associate PPA.

An easier method for developers is to create a tarball. Then the burden of installation is shared by the end-user. They must:

- download the tarball (usually ending in `.tar.gz`).
- decompress source code to a directory.
- compile the source code (unheard of in Windows for Profit world).
- hopefully write down what they've done in case they need to repeat in the future because there is no `apt` database (think Windows installed programs list) that can be backed up.

As another answer already states to another question you asked, you CAN create a tarball and compress data at the same time. A two pass process is NOT required.